# How do I format this string?

Tags: python

```
def count_to_by(n, a):
     if n <= 0:
       return n  
     count_to_by(n - a, a)
     print(str(n) + ", ", end="")
     count_to_by(30, 4)
     input()
```

---

```
Output:        2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30,
Output Needed: 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30
```

Very stuck on this problem. Solution needs recursion, thanks!

Comment: SO is not here to solve your homework problems.

Comment: both output and output needed look the same (except for the trailing comma)

Comment: Link me to documentation so I can learn. Very stuck on this problem...and this is not for homework but for my own studying. Class is done, its december

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/index.html

Comment: @alfasin Yes how would I remove trailling coma? Oh lol sounded stupid I think I got the fix

Comment: You don't want to print a comma after each item, you want to *join* the items with commas.

Comment: You could make it a one-liner by using `range(start, stop, step)` and `', '.join`.

Comment: let your function return a list which you then print any way you want, dont print in every recursive call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make `count_to_by` return a `list`, so it can be more "general purpose".

Then, we can use `', '.join` to print the values:

```
def count_to_by(n, a):
    return [] if n <= 0 else [n] + count_to_by(n - a, a)

print(', '.join(map(str, reversed(count_to_by(30, 4)))))
# 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30
```

---

## EDIT

---

To answer the specific use case of the exercise, you can do something similar to what I did above:

```
def count_to_by(n, m, root=True):
    if n < 1 or m < 1:
         raise ValueError
    try:
        result = [n] + count_to_by(n - m, m, root=False)
    except ValueError:
        result = [n]
    if root:
        print(', '.join(map(str, reversed(result))))
    return result

count_to_by(30, 4)
# 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about using lists except that the practice problem requires an output. The problem can be found here *sigh*

https://www.codestepbystep.com/problem/view/python/recursion/count_to_by

Comment: @CaelanvanOlm See edit

Comment: Beatiful! I will study from your function. Thanks a ton!